# Rahu in vedic astrology

Tags: astrology, raja-yoga, rahu

I read the article about Rahu in [Importance of Rahu in the astrology](https://vedicastrozone.com/importance-of-rahu-in-astrology/) . Also I just want to know some of the auspicious yoga formed by Rahu in birth chart.

Comment: I think many ancient vedic astrology texts dont mention about rahu .